# Access values from keys in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, key-value

In my typescript application, I have the config.json in the following format:

```
EventFilters": [
      {
        "Name": "AppLaunch",
        "Version": "2"
      },
      {
        "Name": "messageDisplayed",
        "Version": "2"
      },
      {
        "ID": "40021",
        "Version": "2"
      }
    ]
```

Now, in my .ts file, I want to read these key value pairs, and I am using the following code:

```
[![let eventfilters: Object\[\] = this.getEventFilters();           // this method reads the event filters from the config, as shown in the image

let keys: Object\[\];
for (let i: number = 0; i < eventfilters.length; i++) {
    keys = Object.keys(eventfilters\[i\]);
    for (let j: number = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        if(eventfilters\[i\]\[keys\[j\]\] === \[/*Parameter 2 to compare*/\]){
            //do something
        }
    }
}]
```

[image: Screenshot from console of eventfilters]

I am trying to compare the values in 'if' statement, using the following 'eventfilters[i][keys[j]]'. However, its throwing  the following error 'Type 'Object' cannot be used as an index type.'.

However, when I use the following statement in the browser console, it returns me the value of the key, 'eventfilters[0][0]'

And due to the version of the typescript and ecmascript, I cannot use the following:

Object.values(eventfilters[i]);
OR
Object.entries(eventfilters[i]);

Apologies for the long question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "keys" variable it is declared as an Object[], and it cannot be used as an index in an array.

You should use a string array in that case:

```
let keys: string[];
```

But, as you don't have a class to store the objects, it's wont work either. The angular can't trust that all the index from the objects it will be always a string.

So, in this case, you can abandon the index approach and use something like:

```
EventFilters.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log('${key} ${value}');
    });
});
```

**Approach not using Object.entries**

You can also force a type to the records on the EventFilters array.

```
const EventFilters: Record<string, any> = [
    {
        "Name": "AppLaunch",
        "Version": "2"
    },
    {
        "Name": "messageDisplayed",
        "Version": "2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "40021",
        "Version": "2"
    }
];


let keys: any[];
for (let i: number = 0; i < EventFilters.length; i++) {
    for (const key in EventFilters[i]) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(EventFilters[i][key]);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as I already mentioned in the question, that I cannot use 'Object.values' & 'Object.entries' because I get this error 'Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.'
According to MDN, Object.entries was officially added in the ES2017 specification, and I am using something that is prior to that and I am not allowed to upgrade it.

Comment: Got it, you need the keys present on the array or just the values?

Comment: We need keys and values both, as keys would be used to extract the value from the second parameter also, in the IF condition above.